# Can the sum be simplified? $\sum_\limits{x=y}^{\infty} {x \choose y}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x+1}$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let:

$$f(y) = \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} {x \choose y} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x+1}$$

Can this be simplified somehow? Is it a standard probability distribution?

I can only get as far as:

$$f(y) = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{x!}{y!(x-y)!} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x}$$

This arose in the context of a probability problem in which X is a geometrically distributed random variable ($p=1/2$) and $Y$ is a binomially distributed random variable ($p=1/2$, $n=x$)

Comment: You should adjust your title...it doesn't match your post

Comment: Are you sure the limits on the sum are that $x$ varies from $y$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Mathematica shows the sum to be $\frac1{2^{y+1}}$.

Comment: The given sum is related to a negative binomial distribution.

Comment: @kennytm: Mathematica is right. Did it say why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the generalized binomial theorem
$(1-z)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+s-1}{s-1}z^k
=\sum_{k=s-1}^{\infty} \binom{k}{s-1}z^{k-s+1}
=z^{-s+1}\sum_{k=s-1}^{\infty} \binom{k}{s-1}z^{k}
$
so that
$\sum_{k=s-1}^{\infty} \binom{k}{s-1}z^{k}
=z^{s-1}(1-z)^{-s}
$
or
$\sum_{k=u}^{\infty} \binom{k}{u}z^{k}
=z^{u}(1-z)^{-u-1}
$.

See, for example,
here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(y) 
&= \sum_{x=y}^{\infty} {x \choose y} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x+1}\\
&= \frac13\sum_{x=y}^{\infty} {x \choose y} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x}\\
&=\frac13(\frac13)^{y}(1-\frac13)^{-y-1}\\
&=(\frac13)^{y+1}(\frac23)^{-y-1}\\
&=(\frac12)^{y+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 4):

$$f(y)=\sum_{x=y}^∞ \binom xy(\tfrac 13 )^{x+1} = {\tfrac 12}^{1+x}$$

> This arose in the context of a probability problem in which X is a geometrically distributed random variable (p=1/3) and Y is a binomially distributed random variable (p=1/2, n=x)

In effect you have a sequence of trials each with three equally probable outcomes: *head, tail, end* and $Y$ is the count of *heads* before the (first) *end*.   **$Y$ is also the count of *heads* before the *end* in all trials which don't show tails.**   In any trial that doesn't show tails, there is an equal probability of instead showing *heads* or an *end*.

Thus $Y\sim\mathcal{Geom}_0(1/2)$ and hence $f_Y(y) = (\tfrac 1 2)^{y+1}$

(Didn't I answer this earlier?)

Comment: You probably did. I know I gave my answer ("Use the binomial theorem, Luke!") to a recent question. As always, comforting when the same answer is gotten by two different methods.